# Difference between eye and Identity in SymPy

Tags: python, matrix, sympy, identity

In SymPy, what is the difference between `eye(5)` and `Identity(5)`?

If I have a matrix `X`, I see that `X + eye(5)` and `X + Identity(5)` give different results (the latter is not a matrix).

Comment: Show us what you do get.  Actual code examples and displays are a lot clearer than word descriptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SymPy distinguishes between

- *explicit matrices*, which have certain size, like 3 by 3, and explicit (possibly symbolic) entries;
- *matrix expressions*, which may have symbolic size, like n by n.

`eye` creates a matrix, `Identity` creates a matrix expression. For example:

```
n = Symbol("n")
A = Identity(n)  # works
A = eye(n)       # throws an error
```

One can do some computations with this object, such as

```
t = trace(A)     # n
B = BlockMatrix([[A, -A], [-A, A]])
```

When possible, a matrix expression can be turned into an explicit matrix with `as_explicit` method:

```
A = Identity(3)
print(A.as_explicit())
```

prints

```
Matrix([
[1, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 1]])
```

One can use `Matrix(A)` to the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

`Identity` is more about being able to use the symbol `I` to stand for the identity. If you want the matrix using that, you have to do `Matrix(Identity)`

See:

```
from random import randint
from sympy import *

X = Matrix(list([randint(1, 10) for _ in range(5)] for _ in range(5)))

print(X + eye(5))
```

> Output: Matrix([[7, 10, 5, 5, 4], [3, 7, 9, 5, 4], [1, 9, 6, 3, 4], [4, 8, 5, 2, 9], [9, 3, 6, 6, 4]])

```
print(X + Matrix(Identity(5)))
```

> Same output: Matrix([[7, 10, 5, 5, 4], [3, 7, 9, 5, 4], [1, 9, 6, 3, 4], [4, 8, 5, 2, 9], [9, 3, 6, 6, 4]])

```
print(X + Identity(5))

'''different output more about the symbol: I + Matrix([
[6, 10, 5, 5, 4],
[3,  6, 9, 5, 4],
[1,  9, 5, 3, 4],
[4,  8, 5, 1, 9],
[9,  3, 6, 6, 3]])'''
```

Not too much is said about it in the [docs](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/expressions.html#sympy.matrices.expressions.Identity).